# React functional component not updating when pushing data to array

Tags: reactjs, components, react-component

I have this functional component which is not updating when pushing data to an array:

```
const Experience = (props) => {
    let experience = [{
        from:"", 
        to:"",
        employer_name:"",
        employer_number:""
    }];

    function addExperience() {
        experience = [...experience, {
            from:"", 
            to:"",
            employer_name:"",
            employer_number:"",
        }];
    }

    return (
        <>
            {experience.map((val, idx) => {
                let id = `exp-id-${idx}`

                return(
                    <div key={idx} id={id}>
                        ...
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            <button onClick={addExperience}>Add experience</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

When Add experience is clicked the mapping is not updated, any help?

Comment: you need to store `experience ` in state. And for that you can either use useState hook or make this a class component and use this.state = {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you're updating the variable, the component itself is not rerendering. A functional component will trigger a render when one of its props update.

In order to get the desired behavior, you have to use state, either with the `useState` hook or by using a class component with state.

#### Functional component with React Hooks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Experience = (props) => {
    const [experience, setExperience] = useState([{
        from:"", 
        to:"",
        employer_name:"",
        employer_number:""
    }]);

    function addExperience() {
        setExperience([...experience, {
            from:"", 
            to:"",
            employer_name:"",
            employer_number:"",
        }]);
    }

    return (
        <>
            {experience.map((val, idx) => {
                let id = `exp-id-${idx}`

                return(
                    <div key={idx} id={id}>
                        ...
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            <button onClick={addExperience}>Add experience</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

#### Class Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Experience extends Component {
    state = {
        experience: [{
            from:"", 
            to:"",
            employer_name:"",
            employer_number:""
        }]
    };

    function addExperience() {
        this.setState([...this.state.experience, {
            from:"", 
            to:"",
            employer_name:"",
            employer_number:"",
        }]);
    }

    return (
        <>
            {this.state.experience.map((val, idx) => {
                let id = `exp-id-${idx}`

                return(
                    <div key={idx} id={id}>
                        ...
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            <button onClick={this.addExperience}>Add experience</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: So how do I change the addExperience function to add an array, the docs page only shows a simple string change

Comment: what are `<>` and `</>` for?

Comment: That's shorthand syntax for fragments: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax